# Stackpanel Layout

Tags: c#, wpf, stackpanel

I have Button with StackPanel content :

```
<Button Width="180" Height="55">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Quantity}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}"/>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemSpecification/>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

What I want to do is laying the 3 TextBlock as this:

http://alrakiza.ly/demo/stackpanel.jpg

I had tried to padding TextBlock but when padding one Textblock all Text Blocks was badding, the same thing with margin.

Can you help me to doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HorizontalAlignment` solve your problem. But parent control must set `width`

```
<Button Height="55">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Width="180">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.Quantity}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemName}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Item.ItemSpecification}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
    </Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying `negative left margin` on first textBlock -

```
<Button Width="180" Height="55">
   <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
       <TextBlock Text="Item1" Margin="-70,0,0,0"/>
       <TextBlock Text="Item2"/>
       <TextBlock Text="Item3"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Output -

[image]